# Parameter is not valid when draw text in label with custom font

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-font

I have label with custom font and timer which change value in label. My app start minimzed. When I displaying the app sometimes exception is displayed and insted of text in label is red cross.

here I try call async method for label text change

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // create a delegate of MethodInvoker poiting to showTime function.
        MethodInvoker simpleDelegate = new MethodInvoker(showTime);
        // Calling showTime Async
        simpleDelegate.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    }
```

font loading

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch); //event handler for windows lock

        File.WriteAllBytes(appPath + "\\font.ttf", Resources.font); //copy font from resources

        try
        {
            PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
            pfc.AddFontFile(appPath + @"/font.ttf");
            label1.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], 11, FontStyle.Bold);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to load nice font." + "\r\n" + "Using standart font instead.", "Time app", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }

    }
```

here is method for label tet change

```
private void showTime()
    {
        label1.Text = time.ToString();
    }
```

******* *Exception Text* *********

```
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
at System.Drawing.FontFamily.GetName(Int32 language)
at System.Drawing.FontFamily.get_Name()
at System.Windows.Forms.Internal.WindowsFont.FromFont(Font font, WindowsFontQuality fontQuality)
at System.Windows.Forms.Internal.WindowsGraphicsCacheManager.GetWindowsFont(Font font, WindowsFontQuality fontQuality)
at System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText(String text, Font font, Size proposedSize, TextFormatFlags flags)
at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.LayoutUtils.MeasureTextCache.GetUnconstrainedSize(String text, Font font, TextFormatFlags flags)
at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.LayoutUtils.MeasureTextCache.TextRequiresWordBreak(String text, Font font, Size size, TextFormatFlags flags)
at System.Windows.Forms.Label.CreateTextFormatFlags(Size constrainingSize)
at System.Windows.Forms.Label.CreateTextFormatFlags()
at System.Windows.Forms.Label.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Label.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Question: how get rid of this exception when Im using custom font?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the `PrivateFontCollection` instance in the `pfc` variable goes out of scope, and *sometimes* gets collected before the control is drawn for the first time (which seems to acquire a strong reference to the instance afterwards).

Move the instance outside the method to prevent GC from collecting it:

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    readonly PrivateFontCollection _pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
    public Form1()
    {
        ...

        _pfc.AddFontFile(appPath + @"/font.ttf");

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any more elegant solution to this?

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example that was used in another question on here. It shows what you need. https://web.archive.org/web/20141224204810/http://bobpowell.net/embedfonts.aspx