# WPF WindowsFormsHost control is not woking showing error

Tags: wpf, winforms, datagridview, windowsformshost

I am using `WindowsFormsHost` to show `DataGridView` in my WPF application.

```
<wfi:WindowsFormsHost Name="winhost" Grid.Row="0" Width="930" Height="200" Margin="5,5,5,0" Visibility="Hidden">
<wf:DataGridView  x:Name="dataGridViewOutlookMailList" ScrollBars="Both" AllowUserToAddRows="False" RowHeadersVisible="False" CellContentClick="dataGridViewOutlookMailList_CellContentClick">
    <wf:DataGridView.Columns>
        <wf:DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Name="dataGridViewCheckBoxColumn3" HeaderText="" Width="25" Visible="True" />
        <wf:DataGridViewTextBoxColumn  Name="dataGridViewTextBoxColumn13" HeaderText="Outlook Entry ID" Width="100" Visible="false" />
        <wf:DataGridViewTextBoxColumn  Name="dataGridViewTextBoxColumn14" HeaderText="FullPath With FileName" Width="100" Visible="False" />
        <wf:DataGridViewTextBoxColumn  Name="dataGridViewTextBoxColumn15" HeaderText="Resume Name" Width="100" Visible="True" />
        <wf:DataGridViewTextBoxColumn  Name="dataGridViewTextBoxColumn18" HeaderText="Sender Name" Width="100" Visible="True" />
        <wf:DataGridViewTextBoxColumn  Name="dataGridViewTextBoxColumn17" HeaderText="Received By Name" Width="100" Visible="True" />
        <wf:DataGridViewTextBoxColumn  Name="dataGridViewTextBoxColumn16" HeaderText="Received" Width="100" Visible="True" />
        <wf:DataGridViewTextBoxColumn  Name="dataGridViewTextBoxColumn19" HeaderText="Sender Address" Width="100" Visible="True"  />
        <wf:DataGridViewTextBoxColumn  Name="dataGridViewTextBoxColumn20" HeaderText="To" Width="100" Visible="True" />
        <wf:DataGridViewTextBoxColumn  Name="dataGridViewTextBoxColumn21" HeaderText="Bcc" Width="100" Visible="True" />
        <wf:DataGridViewTextBoxColumn  Name="dataGridViewTextBoxColumn22" HeaderText="Cc"  Width="100" Visible="True" />
        <wf:DataGridViewTextBoxColumn  Name="dataGridViewTextBoxColumn23" HeaderText="Subject" Width="100" Visible="True" />
        <wf:DataGridViewTextBoxColumn  Name="dataGridViewTextBoxColumn24" HeaderText="Body" Width="100" Visible="True" />
        <wf:DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Name="dataGridViewCheckBoxColumn4" HeaderText="NotesActivity" Width="25" Visible="False" />
        <wf:DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Name="dataGridViewCheckBoxColumn5" HeaderText="Body As Attachment" Width="100" Visible="False" />
    </wf:DataGridView.Columns> 
</wf:DataGridView>
```

I am getting following error while mouse over on datagridview also the UI is not loaded properly. see the screen shot for details.

[image]

I am also using following code

```
WinForms.DataGridViewCellStyle ColStyle1 = new WinForms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection pfc = new System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection();
pfc.AddFontFile(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + @"\NewZrr\OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
foreach (WinForms.DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridViewOutlookMailList.Columns)
{
    c.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(pfc.Families[0], 8, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
}
pfc = null;
```

in my Window_Loaded method to change the font of datagridview. kindly guide me to resolve the issue.

Comment: You should consider improving your post's format. It is almost unreadable...

Comment: @KumaranT I am trying to show you the proper formatting for code block and image.

Comment: As shown in the stack trace, the exception is thrown in the `MouseOver` event handler. Post that piece of code, please.

Comment: @kennyzx: there is no Mouse over event written. As the datagridview not loaded properly as you see in the screen shot itself, i just mouse over on datagridview it throws exception show in screen shot.

Comment: oh yes,...just notice it is caused by the font. Move the `pfc` out of the `Window_Loaded` method, and make it one of the MainWindow's member, and don't set it to null, make it a long-living object, is it working? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44209806/815938

Comment: @kennyzx: that's great i just checked it now it seems working properly.  thanks for your valuable input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `PrivateFontCollection` instance in the `pfc` variable goes out of scope, so when the `DataGridViewCell` is drawn for the first time the specified font cannot be loaded correctly.

Move the `pfc` instance outside the `Window_Loaded` method to prevent GC from collecting it, and do not set it to null, make it a long-living object.

Reference: [Parameter is not valid when draw text in label with custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829344/parameter-is-not-valid-when-draw-text-in-label-with-custom-font)