# Error System.ArgumentException: "Invalid parameter." ShowDialog() when returning to previous form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Help to understand the error. I have several windows that open in turn. The first window works on a timer, that is, after a while it automatically closes and the next one opens. In this window, I have labels that, when clicked, open another form.

The error is that if several times, no matter how long, click on the label and open and close the 3rd form, then in the first one, although I close it, an error occurs:
System.ArgumentException: "Invalid parameter."

First form code:

```
//this is the job of the timer to close
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Opacity == 0)
        {
            timer2.Stop();
            timer1.Stop();
            //Hide this
            this.Hide();
            timer3.Stop();
            this.Close();
        }
        Opacity -= .1;
    }

 // fires on close
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        timer1.Stop();
        timer2.Enabled = false;
        timer2.Stop();
        timer3.Enabled = false;
        timer3.Stop();

        timer1.dispose();
        timer2.dispose();
        timer3.dispose();

        if (GetText().Length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                Form3 form3 = new Form3();
                form3.ShowDialog(); //there is an error, at least points to this place.
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

Form code 2

```
//this is the code that opens another form when the Label is clicked
public void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Form5 form5 = new Form5();
            //for data transfer
            Data.Value = ((Label)sender).Tag.ToString();
            form5.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

if you click it several times, this error will be triggered

Full error code

```
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message = Invalid parameter.
  Source = System.Drawing
  Stack trace:
   at System.Drawing.FontFamily.GetName(Int32 language)
   at System.Drawing.FontFamily.get_Name()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Internal.WindowsFont.FromFont(Font font, WindowsFontQuality fontQuality)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Internal.WindowsGraphicsCacheManager.GetWindowsFont(Font font, WindowsFontQuality fontQuality)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.DrawText(IDeviceContext dc, String text, Font font, Rectangle bounds, Color foreColor, TextFormatFlags flags)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Label.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Label.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Please help me figure out why this error occurs and what are the ways to solve it. This is not happening in my first project where I make such transitions. At the beginning, I thought it was the timers, but as it turned out, it was not.

---

Edited

Yes, I use third-party fonts, I have them downloaded and located in the project folder. This is how I connect them. Is this not the right way? These fonts are in 2 form just.

```
System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection fontCollection = new 
System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection();
            fontCollection.AddFontFile("../../tft\\Roboto-Regular.ttf"); 

        FontFamily family = fontCollection.Families[0];

        System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection fontCollection_family_light = new System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection();
        fontCollection_family_light.AddFontFile("../../tft\\Roboto-Light.ttf"); 
        FontFamily family_light = fontCollection_family_light.Families[0];
```

Comment: It seems like you have an invalid font specified.

Comment: Why would you be trying to show a modal dialogue from a form that has just closed? That makes no sense.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Yes I'm using third party fonts, I've edited my question to indicate how. Am I pointing something wrong?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Thanks, it's really a font loading error

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for pointing out that the error is in the fonts. I fixed my code and yes, it turned out to be better not to install fonts this way. The answer was the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/44209806/18680342

It turned out that it is better to initialize fonts differently

```
readonly System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection _fontCollection = new 
System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection();

    readonly System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection _fontCollection_family_light = new System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection();

public Form5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _fontCollection.AddFontFile("../../tft\\Roboto-Regular.ttf"); // font file
        _fontCollection_family_light.AddFontFile("../../tft\\Roboto-Light.ttf"); // font file
    }
```

And then use like this, wherever you need to install such a font

```
 FontFamily family = _fontCollection.Families[0];

        FontFamily family_light = _fontCollection_family_light.Families[0];
```

Thanks for helping me fix the error! So far it hasn't flown. I will test further!